# How do I rewrite python file with a python script

Tags: python

1. file2.py is just variables
2. I want file1.py to import those variables (import file2) increment them, truncate file2.py and rewrite it with the newly incremented variables

I know how to increment them I'm just not sure how I would rewrite a python file with another python file while that file is also being imported...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import file2

varArr = list_of_variables_in_file2
for var in varArr:
    var += your_increment

with open("file2.py", "w") as file:
    s = ""
    for newVar in varArr:
        s += "your_var_name + " = " + str(newVar) + "\n"
    file.write(s)
```

There is no conflict between the `import` and `write` statements, even if they involve the same file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no conflict with import & write.  Once the import is done, you have all the needed information held locally.  You can overwrite the file without disturbing the values you hold in your run-time space.